# column of stored procedure Will not be displayed in stimulsoft

Tags: stimulsoft

[column of stored procedure Will not be displayed in stimullsoft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6UWi.jpg)

Comment: Please go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Change the Type to Stored Procedure and click on Retrieve Columns